# LDO draining power

Tags: power-supply, batteries, capacitor, ldo, oscillation

I have this weird issue with a TI LDO behaving badly.

In the picture note that I have 2 connectors which can be plugged and unplugged. Connection 1 is just a 5V power supply and connection 2 is a MCU with a battery. The LDO in between have the purpose of stepping 5V down to 3.6V to the MCU side.

Issue is: when I connect "connection 2" first, I have quite a big power drain from the battery. I have confirmed that EN is low. And tried to "restart" EN. If I then connect "connection 1" the LDO goes to 60-70 degrees in temp.

On the other hand, if I connect "connection 1" first, and then "con 2" there is no power drain from the battery, and the LDO stays cool. I can freely unplug and plug "con 1" now. I believe it is not MCU firmware harrassing me since EN stays low.

Lastly (here comes the kicker) if I change C1 to 10uF I can connect them in whatever sequence without draining the battery.

I cannot observe an oscillation on Vin or Vout. What is going on here?

[image]

Comment: What is the exact part number of the LDO? How much is the "big power drain", what is the current and voltage reading?

Comment: Just by "con 2" it is 33 mA. LDO heats up by 10+ degrees. Vout=3.5, Vin=3.3V. LDO is TLV70036DDCR